# JS: ToDataURL doesn't include image when saved through link

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, todataurl

So i'm trying to do a simple photo collage creator and i'm generating the layouts through canvases, let's say i want 4 images, two on each row, so i'm creating 4 canvases. On each of them i have the drop event set so i can load images.
After the images are loaded, you can save the "collage", what i want to do is to get my body background image which is a lorem ipsum random image and draw it on the final canvas as the background.
I got the data from the image, i can see the background on the new canvas, but when i try to save it it doesn't show at all, here is a part of my code:

```
    var imgBackground=new Image();
    var imgBgCanvas = new Image();

    imgBackground.onload = function() {
        //the getDataUrl creates one canvas and i draw the image on it then return the result with .toDataUrl("image/jpeg")
        imgBgCanvas.src=getDataUrl(imgBackground);
    }
    imgBgCanvas.onload= function() {
        //callback to load the image on my canvas, contextColaj is the context of the final canvas
        contextColaj.drawImage(imgBgCanvas,0,0,500,500);
    } 
    imgBackground.crossOrigin="Anonymous";   
    imgBackground.src=$("body").css("background-image").split('"')[1];
```

After this i draw the rest of the canvases on this new canvas, then i return the data to another function that calls the save function.

```
//this is how i draw the canvases, c1 represents the first one but let's say we have four of them, they all show in the final canvas
contextColaj.drawImage(c1, 0, 0, 250, 250); 
//the return 
colaj.toDataURL("image/jpg",1.0);
```

So why are every other canvas images work, they show on the saved file, but the background image is not? If i put them on an image and append them to the body they show up, even the canvas if it's showed on the body has the background image on it.